# Unity: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object with multiple gameObject.SetActive statements

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I encountered that error when trying to hide a gameObject that's a panel. The panel contains a canvas and two buttons.

Initially, the panel is hidden and the script works. The error arises when I try to enable panel.SetActive(true) again and back to panel.SetActive(false).

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EquipmentSlot : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public GameObject panel;

    void Start()
    {
       GameObject panel= GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("panel");
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        GameObject panel= GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("panel");
        panel.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        GameObject panel = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("panel");
        panel.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

I removed any unnecessary code. I'd like for the panel to open and close when hovering over a menu item and just so you know, the hover functions work in my code.

Answer (score 3):

**The problem**

`FindGameObjectWithTag` which afaik is equal to [`GameObject.FindWithTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html) in newer versions doesn't find objects that are inactive!

> Returns one **active** `GameObject` tagged tag. Returns `null` if no `GameObject` was found.

So after setting it to `SetActive(false)` you will not find it again using any of the `Find` variations.

Additinally you are creating a new local variable called `panel` everytime hiding the already existing `panel` instead of using the one you already have.

**Solution**

So instead get the reference while the object is active and only once and re-use it later:

```c#
public class EquipmentSlot : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler/*, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler*/
{
    // if you referenced this in the Inspector e.g. via drag & drop
    // you could completely skip the Find in the start method
    public GameObject panel;

    void Start()
    {
       panel = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("panel");
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        panel.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        panel.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

(Ofcourse if the object was destroyed meanwhile this will give you an exception anyway.)